Is there a hypothetical world in which "I" don't exist but can think?
When I though of this question, I was contemplating the relationship between fallibilism and "I think therefore I am" - René Descartes.
Is it possible for me to imagine that I actually don't exist right now or rather is it possible for you, the reader, to imagine that you don't exist right now. Obviously, we can formulize that you are in a world that doesn't exist and aliens are just manipulating your brain to think things are happening, so I, the one writing this question, wouldn't exist.
I was wondering, is it possible to do something similar with ourselves in context of us. Can I comprehend me being a simulation in someone else's mind?
To simplify: Is it possible that "I" am fallible, that "I" don't exist and was never real but can still think. If so, I would like to how that fact can be comprehended in context of the person who doesn't exist.
Edit: Thanks for all the answers! To clarify any confusion on what I was asking, for future readers, I was prompting whether it is possible for our conscious minds to comprehend that, right now, our consciousness doesn’t exist. So: “can our conscious minds comprehend that our own consciousness is non existent” and when I pondered this though experiment I could say “consciousness doesn’t exist” but I can only come to that conclusion or comprehend it using consciousness. For that reason I posed the question to see how others felt about or could answer the thought experiment. To define what I meant by “I” is our consciousness or being. Sorry for any confusion and please correct me if this is still ambiguous.

Trivial example: the simulation hypothesis. You think you think because you are programmed to think that you think, but there is no you, only a program. Utterly useless as a model of reality unless you think you can find glitches in The Matrix, but useful as a bad example. Where's the tea?

In Hume's bundle theory, thinking could a a fiber of a bundle without an inherent "I" to permanently glue the said bundle...

@keshlam, there's a big difference between your nature being different than you think it is and you not existing at all.  If I'm a program programmed to think anything, then in at least that very sense, I do think.  And I do exist.

To reformulate without biasing the answer: is it possible to imagine that thinking is occurring without the "I" attached? It has been pointed out in relation to Descartes's cogito that thinking occurring is all that introspection actually warrants. Attaching "I" to it is inferential (usually from external identification with the body) but entrenched to a point of mental habit. So there is not even a need for imagining, it is already there, all it takes is to break the habit. Not to say that it is easy, Buddhist meditation might help.

"Is there a hypothetical world . . ." This is nonsense. We can always hypothesise the existence of something, but that doesn't make it true that there is some hypothetical thing beyond what we can call an hypothetical idea.

"in which "I" don't exist but can think?" We can always re-define the notion of "I" and "think" so that this sort of "I" exists and doesn't think. This is too trivial to be of any interest, though.

There is no subject that consciousness is viewed through, so there is no I. Everything in consciousness is within the same field including the “feeling” of being a subject.

I can cheat by making I not a thing in the object model mapping but it doesn't actually get around the needing to exist problem, just makes it impossible to point at.

It seems as if you are asking us to assess the capabilities of your own imagination.  If instead you are pondering this as a "real" question of philosophy, try flipping the question that prompted Descartes' brilliantly simple response.  In other words, try proving that you do not exist..."  (see the problem here?)

Russell notwithstanding: Descartes's Cogito ergo sum is irrefutable. Therein lies its fundamental power.
But as always, the devil is in the detail. We can be sure that we are, but we cannot be sure what we are. We cannot be mistaken about our existence, since we are conscious; but we can be mistaken about the nature of our existence. Indeed, to varying degrees, surely every single one of us is mistaken about some aspects of ourselves. Γνῶθι σεαυτόν, the ultimate philosophical quest, is much older than Descartes, even though it presupposes him.
Yes, we may be dreaming, or we may be current flowing through complex logic gates. Indeed, most of us do not regularly envision our selves as chemical and electrical impulses spreading through our respective connectome. The images on that Wikipedia page seem to have almost nothing to do with ourselves, and yet they are prima facie our mind's physical underpinning.
That our mind "runs" on wetware is probably fairly irrelevant; the mind is an emergent phenomenon. Yes, we might be a "simulation" running on silicone circuits instead of brain cells, but that would not change the essence, let alone the fact of our existence.

Addendum: By pure coincidence (or rather due to the awesome staff at the awesome Otherland bookstore — support your local bookstore!) I just read The Anomaly, an originally French novel from 2020 that received the Prix Goncourt. The book very much explores these ideas.

I came to provide a similar response but you beat me to it and did so very eloquently.

Who and where is this we? You’re missing the point of the question. Consciousness can exist without there being a subject. That is the root of a lot of Buddhist thinking.

@Syed I am -- shame on me -- not familiar with Buddhism. The idea that "consciousness can exist without there being a subject" diametrically contradicts Descartes, and hence probably mainstream Western philosophy. Can you elaborate or provide a pointer for further reading? Also, if you think the question has a Buddhist underpinning, it may be worthwhile to ask a new question making it explicit.

what about the existence of a subject is implied by consciousness necessarily that is so “undeniable”?

@Syed Well, a conscious mind  is by definition the (only) faculty that thinks. Therefore, the presence of a conscious thought by definition implies the presence of a consciousness thinking that thought.

@Syed Oh, I realized that I didn't fully understand your remark, perhaps because I find that concept foreign: You make a distinction between subject and consciousness. To me, they mostly coincide (are congruent, are the same). Both terms are, of course, fairly broad and vague. Perhaps you can try to explain the difference you see, or ask a question about it.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica why would they coincide? Do you think a 1 day old baby has any conception of being a subject peering out in the world?

@Syed A baby is/has not a consciousness, does it/has it? That is, it cannot think Descartes's thought. I'd contend that it is also not a subject (it cannot make decisions).

Concerning your title question:

It is impossible that you think but you do not exist.

Each sentence which states that its subject acts in a certain way presupposes that the subject exist.
Of course you can imagine a world in which you do not exist. But that is not the same world as the world where you exist as a person who imaginates.
Please translate your thoughts into correct language which avoids inconsistencies.

When discussing philosophy you are always forced to use some kind of language and that is a really big restriction because you can not talk about the stuff outside of that language. So any phrase you say is only a construction made by the tool of language and not really anything much that this.
The effort to create, or refute a worldview being baseable on analytic foundations, will always breaks down under self-incoherence of the foundations of logic.
If you are doing philosophy by means of using logic, and you construct a statement, it is not outside of the realm of logic, it is still in it and thus it is just a statement. It can not be outside of "logic" and look down upon us as some meta logic statement that can not be doubted.


As one with a long experience of the difficulties of logic and of the
deceptiveness of theories which seem irrefutable, I find myself unable
to be sure of the rightness of a theory, merely on the ground that I
cannot see any point on which it is wrong.

-Bertrand Russell. May 1922. Introduction to Wittgenstein's Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus.

Most natural languages support some form of propositional logic. If a world-view is inconsistent, then by such a logic, all statements are true. I exist, but also I don't exist. I think a better way to express your thought is something like "the question of whether or not I exist depends upon the ontology I use, which is ultimately a choice of language game. Provide clear and definite definitions to terms, and the question can be answered. In some language games, I don't exist. In others I do."

@MathKeepsMeBusy Agree. You should provide clear and definite definitions, and to those questions, answers can be provided. And about those topics that we can not provide clear and definite definitions, what should we do?

if we lack clear and definite definitions 4 terms in proposition, then either our proposition is algebraic, like "y=x+1" and might be a theorem in our language for which we can legally substitute a variety of values for our undefined term(s), or it is meaningless, in which case, IMHO, we should take a classically skeptical attitude toward it. Its negation might as easily be asserted. We should be no more committed to it, than to its negation. If we are partial to one or the other, we should recognize that our partiality is a subjective choice based on considerations other than truth.

No.
The moment in which "I think", there is "I". Now, "I" might be a regular meatbag human as we know and love them, or a brain in a jar, or a consciousness emerging in a simulated environment, or really just cold bare metal doing the thinking. ”I think therefore I am who I think I am" never was part of the deal. Thinking alone doesn’t tell you anything about being a specific non-GMO human, just as it doesn’t tell you whether you have two kidneys or your heart is about to fail the next instant.
I am. And that’s it.

So, Decartes was trying to doubt everything he could and he ended up at the "fact" that he thought was unquestionable:
"I think therefore I am."
But, astonishingly, people can still question this also by saying:
"What if you don't exist and it is not you that are doing the thinking."
So "I think therefore I am" is in fact not be a "completely without a doubt" kind of a statement. (Bernard Williams and Søren Kierkegaard were early objectors to presupposing "I".)
Than some people tried to fix this by saying:
"A thinking thing thinks." (1)
or
"There is doubt." (2)
So (1) is, let's say, a kind of a tautology, because it is self evidently that it is true by the definition of those words. Any under the term "thing" you can but anything you want.
The statement (2) could be interpreted as a kind of a view that fallibilism could pursue, meaning that "everything can be questioned (even this)",
because if you doubt (2) there is still doubt, so you are not contradicting a statement, but reafirming it.
One can view fallibilism in this way as immune to paradoxes or doubt, because it right from the beginning says that it can be doubted,i.e. it is in its "defintion" that it can be doubted (so doubting it doesn't contradict it).

So fallibilism can be seen as not really as a "constructing theory" that is trying to prove or disprove anything, it can be seen only like a tool in inquiry, that helps us to always improve our knowledge.
So yes, "Cogito ergo sum." can indeed be prone to further investigations, everything can.


Is it possible for me to imagine that I actually don't exist right now

You can imagine what you want. That's what the imagination is for. We can imagine all sorts of crazy things such as square circle. But this doesn't negate Descartes cogito. You thought, and therefore you exist.
